# Sum range and subtract sum of subrange

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am calculating overtime. If hours are greater than 40, subtract 40. Simple enough. However, with a **single** copy/paste *formula*, I want to break this down to show how many hours are counted as overtime for *each day* of the week. Here is a visual example:

```
Date | Hours | OT |
-----|-------|----|
Day1 | 10    | 00 | 
Day2 | 08    | 00 |
Day3 | 18    | 00 |
Day4 | 16    | 12 | OT = if SUM(B2:B5>40) then SUM(B2:B5,-40,SUM((C2:C4)*-1))
Day5 | 04    | 04 |
Day6 | 08    | 08 |
Day7 | 09    | 09 |
```

My big issue here is that I don't always want to start at `B2`&`C2` and I don't want to always end at `B5`&`C4` because the week starts over and I need to know my current cell (`B5`) and the cells within the week on the next column -1 row each day (`C4`). I need `B2` to `increment` to `B9` to `B16` etc and I need `C4` to increment **with** `B5`. i.e. `B7`&`C6`, `B6`&`C5` etc. I think that `OFFSET` can work, but I don't know how to get it to work so that I can use one formula instead of 52 derivatives of one.

So far the best formula I could come up with is:
`=SUM(OFFSET($B$2,(ROW()-2)*7,0,7,1),-40)`
Which only calculates the total overtime for an entire week and statics `B2`.

***ANSWERED:***
Thanks to @TomSharpe. Either of these are perfect. Choose whichever you like best:

**OFFSET**

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(SUM(OFFSET($C$2,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7,0,MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)))=0,--TEXT(SUM(OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7,0,MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)+1))-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

**INDEX**

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(SUM(INDEX(C:C,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7+2):C1)=0,--TEXT(SUM(INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7+2):B2)-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

Comment: Is date always day and a number, and day 8 is after day 7? Or will you start over with day1? Or does the column contain an actual date?

Comment: It would be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an offset formula which starts again with the overtime calculation each week. The offset is to the start of the current week, and the height is the day number in the current week. I realised eventually that when the overtime for the previous day is greater than zero, the overtime for the current day is just the number of hours worked on the current day (because they are all overtime).

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(C1=0,--TEXT(SUM(OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7,0,MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)+1))-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

The use of the TEXT function is a trick suggested by @Barry Houdini which saves repeating the whole formula when the result is negative.

It would be nice to do this using INDEX instead of OFFSET and time permitting I will see if it can be done that way.

[image]

Here is the INDEX version - slightly easier because the end of the range is just the current cell in column B.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(C1=0,--TEXT(SUM(INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7+2):B2)-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

*EDIT*

As pointed out by OP, I had forgotten about days with zero hours worked. So my OFFSET formula should be

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(SUM(OFFSET($C$2,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7,0,MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)))=0,--TEXT(SUM(OFFSET($B$2,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7,0,MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)+1))-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

And my INDEX formula should be

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($2:$2),7)=0,0,IF(SUM(INDEX(C:C,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7+2):C1)=0,--TEXT(SUM(INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW()-ROW($2:$2))/7)*7+2):B2)-40,"0;\0"),B2))
```

The overtime worked on the first day of the week is always set to zero (even if you were to enter say 50 hours) on the basis that in practice you can't work more than 24 hours a day: if you wanted to change the goalposts so that it worked for a whole team of people, I think that would be another question.

[image]

Comment: Looks great but i really don't understand how the whole thing works. Where would i go to get a better idea of how this is working please? For row 2 i started evaluating and was confused when i saw syntax like SUM(INDEX(B:B,{2}):B3)-40

Comment: INDEX returns a reference so it's OK to use it so specify either end of a range using the ordinary notation <ref1>:<ref2>. There is an example right at the end of the documentation here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd =SUM(B2:INDEX(A2:C6, 5, 2)) which evaluates to =sum(B2:B6) but they don't exactly spell out how useful this can be.

Comment: I suppose you could look at that way but in my answer there is only one column in the range so the start of the range is the intersection of the row given by the expression INT((row() ... etc ) with column 1 in the range B:B which boils down to B2, and the end of the range (if you're evaluating it on row 3) is just B3.

Comment: This seems to work, but with a couple kinks. Look at rows 5 thru 8 from [this picture](https://pasteboard.co/GYkUix2.png) Let's forget that you can't work more than 24hrs a day for a second. Even after stepping through, I still don't understand how it results in assigning overtime when 0 is entered. @TomSharpe

Comment: You're right, I do need to add up all the overtime for the week as you said in your question and not just look at the previous day so my assumption about the overtime being just the hours worked if the previous day's overtime was zero was wrong (I forgot about days when there was no work).